# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent - Finding all id's through multiple relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

So here are my relationships:

A fund belongs to a planCode

A planCode belongs to a planType

What I need to do is find the fund_id's that are a part of certain plan types. I tried something like this:

`$plans = (new 'App\PlanType')->with('planCode.fund')->whereIn('code', ['PENS', 'ANN', 'WEL'])->get();`

With this I get the three plan codes with their relationships eager loaded. What I want is a list of all the fund_id's. I tried `$plans->lists('planCode.fund.fund_id', 'code')` but this returns null for the fund_id. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you can do this using a hasManyThrough relationship.

Comment: @atefth Is right, check out [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) in Laravel documentation.

Comment: wow....ive been finding hacks around a lot of this...totally missed this relationship somehow. Thanks. Want to flesh out an answer with that?

Comment: thanks @C.Liddel :Dl, I've posted an answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if your relationships are like this -

> **PlanCode** *has many* **Funds**
>
> **Fund** *belongs to* a **PlanCode**
>
> **PlanType** *has many* **PlanCodes**
>
> **PlanCode** *belongs to* a **PlanType**

Then you can add another relationship like this -

> **PlanType** *has many* **Funds** *through* **PlanCodes**

**UPDATE**

After adding a function like this to your **PlanType** class -

```
public function funds() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('fund', 'planCode', PT, PC);
}
```

You can simply access **Funds** on your **PlanType** model like this -

```
$planType->Funds
```

Take a look at the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

Comment: CAn you add Nocardium's code / explanation to your answer? It might help clarify for others

Answer (score 1):

Yep, atefth has it in one. Laravel has a really useful relationship so that you don't have to make repeated queries to the database to get relations of relations. This is the hasManyThrough relationship.

So here, for example, your planType model has many fund models *through* the planCode model. Your planType model should contain a funds method that looks like this, where PC is the planCode->id column name in the fund table, and PT is the planType->id column in the planCode table:

```
public function funds() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('fund', 'planCode', PT, PC);
}
```

You may have to fully namespace your models, depending on the structure of your application.